# Compiling PostGIS fails when it can't find GDALAllRegister

Tags: postgis, installation, compile

I'm trying to compile the latest PostGIS 2.1.0 beta and the configure process fails at:

```
checking GDAL version... 1.10.0
checking for OGR enabled... yes
checking gdal.h usability... yes
checking gdal.h presence... yes
checking for gdal.h... yes
checking ogr_api.h usability... yes 
checking ogr_api.h presence... yes
checking for ogr_api.h... yes
checking cpl_conv.h usability... yes
checking cpl_conv.h presence... yes
checking for cpl_conv.h... yes
checking for library containing GDALAllRegister... no
configure: error: could not find GDAL
```

GDAL is installed to the normal /usr, and gdal-config is in my path, and the process still fails if I specify its location when I call ./configure.  Configuration works if I specify --without-raster, but none of the PostGIS extensions are built, only the old fasioned .sql files so I can use ALTER EXTENSION to update my PostGIS database.  Any ideas?

Comment: How did you install gdal?

Comment: Built it myself with the following options:  ./configure --prefix=/usr --with-netcdf --with-libtiff --with-sqlite3 \
              --with-geotiff --with-mysql --with-python --without-libtool --with-curl \
              --with-hdf5 --with-perl --with-geos --with-png \
              --with-fgdb=/opt/FileGDB_API

Comment: It worked just fine with PostGIS the last time I compiled it, that was a SVN pull of PostGIS

Comment: Have you tried compiling using the -with-gdal-config flag? Example from my system: –with-gdalconfig=/usr/local/bin/gdal-config

Comment: Take a minute to look the "config.log", usually you can find the error explained.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried --with-gdalconfig and it didn't help.  I'll check out the log when I get home this evening.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had this problem and I found out the path to the libraries was missing.
To see if something is missing, check the  `/root/postgis-2.1.0/config.log` for hints.

I had traced the following problems while searching for errors in the `config.log` file by the string 'needed by'.

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libhdf5.so.6, needed by /usr/lib64/libgdal.so, not found
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libpq.so.5, needed by /usr/lib64/libgdal.so, not found
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libhdf5_hl.so.6, needed by /usr/lib64//libnetcdf.so.6
```

Solution:
I searched for their location by searching for the missing files, E.G. `find / -name 'libhdf5.so.6'` and I found them.

They were in:

```
/usr/lib64/mpich2/lib/libhdf5.so.6.
/usr/lib64/mpich2/lib/libhdf5_hl.so.6
/opt/postgresql/9.3/lib/libpq.so.5
```

I simply added the paths to the file /etc/ld.so.conf which now looks like:

```
include ld.so.conf.d/*.conf
/opt/postgresql/9.3/lib/
/usr/lib64/mpich2/lib/
```

Then run `ldconfig` and it all worked!

Comment: My config.log didn't show these info. I had to do `ldd` on libgdal itself to get the info on the missing libraries. Hope this helps others too!